# Creating A Legend by Iteration over ee.List() Object Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, legend, gui

The Goal is to adapt the Legend from the Example for my Data
I just Changed the Following:

In the original the names and their palettes of subclasses are separated in different subclasswise-properties, I guess that is why they need these lines to obtain **palette** and the **names**

```
// Get the list of palette colors and class names from the image.
image.toDictionary().select([BAND_NAME + ".*"]).evaluate(function(result) {
  var palette = result[BAND_NAME + "_class_palette"];
  var names = result[BAND_NAME + "_class_names"];
  loading.style().set('shown', false);

  for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    legend.add(makeRow(palette[i], names[i]));
  }
  Map.addLayer(image, {min: 0, max: 17, palette: palette}, 'IGBP classification');
});
```

the **names** and **palette** in the case of CORINE by Copernicus are easier obtained

`var names = ee.List(lc2012.get('landcover_class_names'))
var landcoverPalette = ee.List(lc2012.get('landcover_class_palette'))`

extracting Values by indexing over theese `ee.List()` Objects by e.g. `names[0]` won´t work. Instead one has to use `names.get(0)`

`print()names.get(0)` retrieves a Computed Object that looks like a string --> `'Artificial surfaces; urban fabric; continuous urban fabric'`

but used inside a function e.g. `legend.add(makeRow('E6004D', names.get(0)))`, it doesnt get the string, but instead delivers this
[image]

[Code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/2d565b31139ecee8cfc6703101f628f3)

I do not understand how to access my List and retrieve the wanted element

`for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    legend.add(makeRow(landcoverPalette[i], names[i]));
}`

The legend won´t load fully

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing server-side and client-side variables, that's why it does not work. The function for creating the legend was correct.

Try this: [link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/ba2fe113c9340893bf2e14148d35f1c6)